# Sails-mysql Oauth

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

i am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/CanTireInnovations/OAUTH-Server-with-Sails-and-AngularJS/blob/master/OAUTH_README.md)  to make oauth server with mongodb, and with mongodb it works fine.

But then i try to change to sails-mysql, but i am having some problems, for example if i change the connection to mysql, if i try to create new client/user it works... but then, if i want to verifi the link, it returns this error:

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'undefined AND `tokens`.`access_token` undefined AND `tokens`.`access_token` unde' at line 1
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23)
at Parser.write (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:92:28)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
at PoolConnection.Connection.query (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:197:25)
at __FIND__ (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:836:20)
at Object.module.exports.adapter.find (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:803:9)
at Array.async.auto.findRecords (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:1056:21)
at /home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:484:38
at _each (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
at Object.async.auto (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:455:9)
at __DESTROY__ (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:1053:15)
at afterwards (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:84:5)
at /home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:40:7
at Ping.onPing [as _callback] (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:94:5)
at Ping.Sequence.end (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:105:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23)
at Parser.write (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/mpinto/Escritorio/Guatour/oauth-server/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:92:28)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)

Details:  Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'undefined AND `tokens`.`access_token` undefined AND `tokens`.`access_token` unde' at line 1
```

Generated mysql script:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: oauth
-- ------------------------------------------------------ 
-- Server version   5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,       FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE,    SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `clients`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `clients`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`organization` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`client_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`client_secret` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`trust_level` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`redirect_uri` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`date_registered` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`date_verified` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `client_id` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `clients`
--

LOCK TABLES `clients` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `clients` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `clients` VALUES       (NULL,NULL,'mpinto@estratek.com','LdjM89WLIxrKnxExtXHUcq7ViucW20Kj','pew1d    XFNWpuTnTjEGhYX495DUhxtDwUH',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `clients` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `tokens`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tokens`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
`access_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`refresh_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`expiration_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`client_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`security_level` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`scope` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tokens`
--

LOCK TABLES `tokens` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tokens` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tokens` VALUES     ('opSlFDZcPxrFFL0XvLWxiIsyxRZJcIcl','WIwl2x5ZbXBxXUHTC1JUlgAKDtXovPZe','qx    RalLE3asf6LCQgclr8GtQ22vtgn1lb',NULL,'2015-06-    25','LdjM89WLIxrKnxExtXHUcq7ViucW20Kj',NULL,NULL,1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tokens` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`date_registered` date DEFAULT NULL,
`date_verified` date DEFAULT NULL,
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`encrypted_password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

LOCK TABLES `users` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2015-06-25 14:58:43
```

How can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the SQL it generates?

Comment: sure, i updated the question with the script sql

Comment: Not the SQL you are showing me, the SQL that is being sent to the database during execution. Your database dump looks fine. You can figure it out by looking at the code or doing a tcpdump.

Comment: well, i just found a solution, i change the queries, to DB. Using Waterline findOne with mysql give me error, so i updated that to my own queries to db, and that works for me.